# Implement DFS algorithm correctly to optimize an irrigation

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

The official task introduction:

*Irrigation canals are a key innovation that allowed the Egyptian agriculture to flourish since the ancient times. In this problem, we will represent the set of irrigation canals in Egypt as an undirected graph, with nodes of the graph corresponding to the junctions and edges of the graph corresponding to the actual canals.*

*To avoid difficulties with controlling the water flow, there must be no cycles in this graph. In other words, this graph is a forest. Note that it is not necessarily a tree, or in other words it is not necessarily connected. Some junctions might even have no canals connected to them, in other words the graph may have isolated vertices.*

*Some nodes in this graph correspond to the water sources (typically a junction with a river, or a spring). You need to redesign the existing canal system to maximize the number of junctions that are connected to at least one water source through the canals. In other words, you need to maximize the total size of the connected components containing at least one water source node.*

*The canal construction is hard work, so you need to do the redesign one improvement at a time. In one improvement, you can choose one junction as the pivot junction, destroy one of the canals connected to the pivot junction, and build a new canal connecting the pivot junction to any other junction. Since we destroy one canal and build one canal, the total number of canals stays the same. You may not introduce cycles when building the new canals, in other words the graph must still be a forest after each improvement. In particular, you may not have more than one canal between the same pair of junctions, or connect a junction to itself. You may not choose a junction with no connected canals as the pivot junction, since there would be no canal to destroy.*

*You can do multiple improvements, but to avoid concentrating too much construction work in one place, each junction may be touched by improvements at most once. Note that each improvement touches three junctions: the pivot junction, the one it is being disconnected from, and the one it is being connected to.*

*Your goal is to find such a sequence of improvements that touches each junction at most once, and after all improvements are made the number of junctions that are connected to at least one water source is as high as possible. Note that the number of improvements that you do does not matter, only the end result.*

#### Input

The first line contains the number of test cases T.
T test cases follow of the following format:

- The first line contains three integers N — the number of junctions, M — the number of canals, and K — the number of junctions that are water sources.
- The next M lines contain two junction numbers each, denoting two junctions connected by a canal. The junctions are numbered from 0 to N-1.
- The next line contains K distinct junction numbers that are water sources.

#### Example Input

```
2
3 1 1
0 2
1
6 3 1
1 2
3 4
4 5
0
```

I need to redesign the existing canal system to maximize the number of junctions connected to at least one water source through the canals.

There's the official output instructions below.

#### Output

For the t-th test case, output a line containing “Case #t:”, followed by two integers S and P: the number of junctions that you have managed to connect to at least one water source through the canals (directly or indirectly), and the number of improvements that you have made to do so.

In the i-th of the following P lines, print three integers a_i, b_i, and c_i: the number of the pivot junction, the number of the junction that the canal being destroyed connects the pivot junction to, and the number of the junction that the canal being built connects the pivot junction to.

In case there are multiple solutions that lead to the maximum amount of junctions connected to at least one water source, you may output any such solution.

#### Example Output

```
Case #0: 2 1
0 2 1
Case #1: 4 2
2 1 5
4 3 0
```

I have written this python script below to the point where I am able to parse the input file and input the data into a DFS class. This works fine.

Now I'm stuck because I now need to improve the canal connections so as many junctions as possible are connected to a water source but I can't wrap my head around how to do that.

Python script:

```py
inputFile = open("subtask-1-input.txt", "r")
inputFileLines = enumerate(inputFile.read().split("\n"))

# 
# Final values needed
# 
amountTestCases = None;
irrigations = []

# 
# Temp vars
# 
tempIrrigation = []
tempCanalsCount = None;
tempCanalConnections = []

tempBlockedIndexes = []

#
# Input file parser
# 
for index, line in inputFileLines:
  if index == 0:
    amountTestCases = int(line.split()[0])
    continue

  # N, M, K line
  if len(tempIrrigation) == 0:
    [junctions, canals, watersources] = map(int, line.split())
    tempCanalsCount = canals
    tempIrrigation.extend([junctions, canals, watersources])
    continue
  
  # Canal connections
  if len(tempIrrigation) == 3:
    if(tempCanalsCount != 0):
      tempCanalConnections.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
      tempCanalsCount -= 1
      continue
    else:
      tempIrrigation.append(tempCanalConnections)

  # Watersource indexes line at the end of each test case
  tempIrrigation.append(list(map(int, line.split())))

  irrigations.append(tempIrrigation)

  # Clean up temporary variables
  tempCanalsCount = None
  tempIrrigation = []
  tempCanalConnections = []

# 
# DFS class
# 
class DFSGraph():
  def __init__(self):
    self.graph = {}

  def add_edge(self, u, v):
    if u not in self.graph:
      self.graph[u] = []
    if v not in self.graph:
      self.graph[v] = []
    self.graph[v].append(u)
    self.graph[u].append(v)

# 
# Recursive improvement function
# 
def improve(prev, arr, graph):
  print("Hey")

# 
# Insert data points into DFS graph
# 
for index, irrigation in enumerate(irrigations):
  [junctions, canals, watersources, canalConnections, waterSourceIndexes] = irrigation
  dfs = DFSGraph()

  # Add canal connections to dfs graph
  for conn in canalConnections:
    dfs.add_edge(conn[0], conn[1])

  print(irrigation)
  print(dfs.graph)

  # Sort graph by size of value array
  sorted_key_list = sorted(dfs.graph, key=lambda key: len(dfs.graph[key]))
  sorted_dict = { key: dfs.graph[key] for key in sorted_key_list }

  print(sorted_dict)
```

Thanks to everyone taking the time to read this and maybe being able to help.

Comment: What counts as improvement?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI When a canal connection e.g. between A and B gets "improved" so A and C are connected all A B C got an "improvement" or "change" so they can't be used anymore.

Comment: The explanation doesn't make sense. The instructions say "the number of the junction that the canal being destroyed connects the pivot junction to, and the number of the junction that the canal being built connects the pivot junction to". So it looks like an improvement is a destruction of one canal and a construction of another one. Please quote the official rules.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI oh I'm sorry for my bad explanation. Yes this is true.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the official definition of "improvement".

Comment: In addition to failing to define an "improvement", it looks like you've swapped the words "junction" and "canal" several times, which makes it very difficult to make sense of what you wrote.  I think you want to maximize connected junctions, for example, even though you said to maximize connected canals.  The details are important, and you can't expect people to just "know what you mean" when you write imprecisely.  You can't expect to solve problems like this if you're thinking about them imprecisely.

Comment: This doesn't look like an official definition. An official definition would mention that the two canals, one being destroyed and one being built, have a common junction. It would also mention which of the involved junctions are improved by the action. For the third time, please quote the official rule. Better still, just copy the official problem statement in its entirety and without any editing.

Comment: @MattTimmermans You're right, I apologize. Didn't notice it when writing because my head's a mess after trying with that for a long time.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I now put the whole task description above where the definitions are included.

Comment: Despite too many confusing words, the problem looks trivial. (1) Find a wet tree.  (2) Find a dry tree. (3) In a wet tree, remove a channel leading to a leaf and connect its parent to a dry tree. (4) Rinse and repeat.  If there are `k` dry trees, you need exactly `k` improvements, and you'd end up with exactly `k` dry nodes.

Comment: @user58697 Not so fast. Good news are, if you have a wet tree with more than one source, you can connect a dry tree without disconnecting any nodes. Bad news are, what happens if you have more dry trees than wet trees? You need to take care not to use the same node twice. Note that each improvement makes *three* nodes ineligible.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes I need to keep that in mind. But at the end it's not the goal to connect all just connect as many as possible and there could be some dry trees that stay dry.

Comment: Suppose you have this configuration w1-d1 d2-d3 d4-d5-d6. If you mindlessly disconnect d1 and connect d2, the algorithm above gets stuck and you are left with 4 dry nodes, while the best result is 2. You can modify the algorithm, say, by disconnecting a node from a *dry* tree instead, but it is not trivial to come up with a method that always gives the best possible result.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI So what should I exactly do? To be honest I'm actually stuck I'm currently drawing every tree and trying to think about how to connect them the best and also implement that technically...

Comment: I was thinking about going from each wet tree and then adding the biggest dry trees to the end one by one. Is that even a good approach? For that I first need to find the dry trees.

Comment: "going from each wet tree and then adding the biggest dry trees to the end one by one" Not necessarily the best one. Say you have a single isolated source. There is nothing to disconnect from it, but you still can connect a dry tree to it. Of course you better choose the biggest one. Now what if all your dry trees have two nodes? Not trivial as I said.

Comment: Yeah I understand. It doesn't make it easier.. annoying.